Why the work done by surrounding on the piston is same as average work done by surrounding on the gas inside the cylinder?
In thermodynamics when we derive the formula for work done by the surrounding on the gas, we actually derive the formula for work done by the surrounding on the piston and say that let the surrounding is imparting average force F and the piston moves dx so work done (dW) is F.dx and then we divide and multiply the expres by the area of the piston and get dW= -Pext.dV. (-ve sign to account that work is done BY the surrounding)
But it's the work done on the PISTON. If we really want to calculate the actual work done by the surrounding on the gas inside the cylinder we have to account for individual forces acting and displacement over time for each of the  molecule inside the cylinder but we say that it averages out and gives us this expression. But how do we know that it averages out? I mean the pressure is average force per unit area derived from kinetic theory of gases that's alright. So the  force on piston would be the same as average force on gas inside the cylinder as the piston is frictionless and massless by assumption. But the average displacement of each molecule of gas would be same as the displacement of piston and average out to the change in volume of the gas ,how do we know it?
Edit - As it seems, some people are misunderstanding my question. So I am clearing it here, suppose we have two rigid blocks touching each other and one block is massless(neg. Mass) and if we apply force on 1 block, we can be completely sure that the displacement of the other block would be same as 1st block so we can use F.dx where dx is displacement of massless block for calculating work done on the 2nd block. But here the 2nd block is GAS which is not rigid so how can we be sure that it's displacement would be same as the displacement of piston? As all of the molecules of gas are moving randomly how do we make sure that it averages out to be the displacement of piston?

If you draw a free body diagram of the piston and do a force balance on the piston,, what do you get?

@ChetMiller Miller I have mentioned it the average force and hence the pressure of the surrounding on the gas would be same as the pressure on the piston. But what about the volume? How can we say that the displacement of piston is same as the average displacement of all the molecules inside the cylinder and hence work done on the piston and the gas means the SAME

Also can u please explain why in chemistry we  apply this formula for irreversible process because we know what Pext. Is and dV is but in physics we use Pinternal to calculate work done by the gas which is inside the cylinder and hence We say that for irreversible process it is very difficult to determine so we can't calculate the work done by the gas but in chemistry we CAN calculate the work done even for irreversible process. Why the  inconsistency in different branch of science??

@VirenderBhardwaj  The work done by a force equals the force times the displacement of the point of application of the force. Period. The results of the work done by the force is a separate issue.

It is not the average displacement of all the gas molecules in the cylinder that matters.  It is the force of the gas molecules hitting the piston times the displacement of the piston that determines the work done by the gas.

In an irreversible process, the force exerted by the gas molecules hitting the piston is not known.  So, if we explicitly know the force exerted by the surroundings on the massless frictionless piston, we can use that instead (and get the right answer).

@ChetMiller but that will give us the work done by surrounding on the PISTON . In order to be sure that it will be the same as work done on the gas we have to know the forces on each molecule inside the cylinder( that will be the same as average force on piston ) and their displacements over time but how come we are sure that the displacement of piston  would be the same as average displacement of the molecules?

@ChetMiller suppose we have two rigid blocks touching each other then we can be completely sure that the displacement of the one object will be equal to the other....so to calculate work done we can assume our system to be the complete set of two blocks and calculate F.dx but here we have a gas and not rigid object. How can we be sure that displacement of piston equals the average displacement of all the molecules of gas? I hope you'll understood what my confusion is

The displacement of the piston does not have to equal the displacements of the gas molecules.  And, the work done by the gas on the piston is equal to the force exerted by the gas molecules on the piston times the displacement of the piston.  And, from Newton's 3rd law, the magnitude of the force exerted by the gas molecules on the piston is equal to that of the piston on the gas molecules.

@ChetMiller do you understand what the OP is saying in the Edit? Because I don’t


But it's the work done on the PISTON.

I will only address this statement, as some of your other statements are not clear (at least to me).
There is no net work done on the piston unless (1) it compresses and/or (2) there is a change in the kinetic energy of its center of mass.
Let's assume the piston is a rigid (non deformable) body in a horizontally oriented cylinder. Since it is incompressible there will be no change in its internal energy due to work. Then, per the work energy theorem, the net work done on the piston will equal its change in macroscopic kinetic energy, i.e., the change in kinetic energy of its center of mass.
If the piston is initially at rest before the external pressure is applied and ends at rest when the compression of the gas ends when equilibrium is restored, the change in kinetic energy is zero. Therefore, the net work done on the piston is zero. Since the cylinder is horizontally oriented, there will be no change in its gravitational potential energy.
Under the above assumptions, we can conclude that non of the energy transferred from the surroundings in the form of work, is retained by the piston. All of the energy transfer from the surroundings in the form of work winds up in the gas.
That said, the piston still has a potential role in the final equilibrium state due to the possibility of heat transfer from the gas, undergoing a temperature increase due to compression, to the piston. But that's a separate matter.
Hope this helps.

As I understand from your answer, it means we are actually considering our system as (piston + gas inside) and as the surrounding does work on piston and piston does work on gas , it will increase the energy of the SYSTEM. But as our piston is assumed to be massless. So we are ignoring that it possess any kind of energy. So all of the change of energy occurs inside the gas only . Am I right?

@VirenderBhardwaj Yes you are right. But we only need to assume the piston is massless because of its volumetric heat capacity (not because of energy transfer by work). And that's because of heat transfer from the gas to the piston when they come into thermal equilibrium. If the volumetric heat capacity  of the piston is negligible compared to that of the gas, we can consider the gas only as our system.

Volumetric heat capacity? I didn't understand. If the piston would have some mass then the work done would contribute to its energy as well along with the gas...Am i wrong?

@VirenderBhardwaj are you saying you don't understand what "volumetric heat capacity" means?

By Volumetric heat capacity you mean ...basically you are saying that they both (gas and piston) conduct heat at nearly the same rate? But am I wrong in thinking that if the piston have some mass the work done will contribute to its energy as well. But we are making assumptions that there is no friction and no energy transfered to the piston?

@VirenderBhardwaj  This is going to require more discussion that this site allows under comments. Are you willing to continue it in the Chat room?

Alright, I am okay to continue the discussion if you can explain this to me in simpler terms about what are our assumptions exactly and why  are we making those specific assumptions

Before we do, did you understand the last comment by Chet Miller?

@BobD  He seems to be saying that to get the work done by a gas, you need  to multiply the force exerted by the gas by the displacement of all the gas molecules.  But the work done on an object is equal to the force on the object times the displacement of the object, not the entity causing the force.

@ChetMiller Sorry, but are you referring to my question to you under your post about what he is saying in the edit to his post?

@BobD yes I have understood that it's the displacement of the point of application of force which is seen not the entire object / each particle while calculating work....but still now the question is that the work is being done on the piston by the external force so it will contribute in its energy as well along with the energy of the gas inside the cylinder right? But we assume it to be massless and frictionless so basically it is negligible and we don't consider it. But you said it's massless because of some other reasons which I don't understand

@VirenderBhardwaj 1. If we assume the piston is massless, it becomes totally irrelevant except for the fact that it acts as part of the boundary between the gas and the surroundings. The work done by the surroundings is due to the displacement of that boundary. 2. If we consider the piston to have mass, but is a rigid body that begins and ends at rest, positive work done on the piston by the surroundings equals the negative work done on the piston by the gas, for a net work of zero.  The piston acquires no energy due to work. It merely acts as an intermediary.


BUT, the piston can acquire energy from the gas by means of heat, due to the temperature rise of the gas relative to the piston. But this is heat, not work. 4. If we consider the piston as part of the surroundings, and not part of the system,  we can again ignore the piston. 5. BUT if, for some reason (and I can’t for the moment think of one), we wish to include the piston as part of the system, we must consider its heat capacity along with that of the gas, because its internal energy would be part of the systems internal energy.


I can’t explain this any clearer.
